# Retrieving Integers using sscanf

Tags: c++, string, integer, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char P_input[101];
    int Bug_Time[10][4];
    int Tot_Time[4];
    char rimp[10];
    cout<<"Enter Total time:"<<endl;
    cin.getline(P_input,100);
    cout<<P_input<<endl;
    sscanf(P_input, "%d Days - %d - Hours - %d - Minutes - %d Seconds", Tot_Time[0],Tot_Time[1],Tot_Time[2],Tot_Time[3]);
    cout<<Tot_Time[0]<<Tot_Time[1]<<Tot_Time[2]<<Tot_Time[3]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It returns output

```
> Enter Total time:
> 0 Days - 0 - Hours - 26 - Minutes - 56 Seconds //I entered this 
> 0 Days - 0 - Hours - 26 - Minutes - 56 Seconds // It showed me this 
> 1576 1558 0 7762 //Final cout
```

Can someone help me with this. I want it to display "0 0 26 56"

Comment: What's wrong with just using [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) actually?

Comment: sscanf takes pointers to its output parameters. And there are better C++ methods to use (Edit: see @πάνταῥεῖ comment for a more helpful C++ method).

Answer (score 3):

```
sscanf(P_input, "%d Days - %d - Hours - %d - Minutes - %d Seconds", Tot_Time[0],Tot_Time[1],Tot_Time[2],Tot_Time[3]);
```

The `sscanf` function comes from the C API and does not use references. All of your parameters are being passed by value, and all of the integers are uninitialized, so passing their values to `sscanf()` doesn't make any sense.  You need to pass them by pointer instead.

Comment: How the heck does this not throw a seg fault?  Memory location 0 is certainly out of bounds?

Comment: @ojblass Undefined Behavior. Since the values in `Tot_Time` are uninitialized they are _not_ `0` and may in fact contains values that when used as a pointers end up pointing to valid memory.

Answer (score 1):

`sscanf()` expects a **pointer** to an `int` for the `%d` specifier. You are not passing pointers to your integers, though.  The call needs to look like this instead:

```
sscanf(P_input, "%d Days - %d - Hours - %d - Minutes - %d Seconds", &Tot_Time[0], &Tot_Time[1], &Tot_Time[2], &Tot_Time[3]);
```

Also, your final `cout` is not outputting spaces between the numbers, like you said you wanted:

```
cout << Tot_Time[0] << ' ' << Tot_Time[1] << ' ' << Tot_Time[2] << ' ' << Tot_Time[3] << endl;
```

Comment: Works fine for me when I try it. Double check the format of the data you are typing in. And you should also check the return value of `sscanf()`, it will tell you how many values it actually extracted. If it is not returning 4 then something went wrong.